# Insecure Snowflake Console Access

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have my snowflake warehouse hosted on an address that looks like this :
*********.snowflakecomputing.com/console (not sure where it is hosted - maybe within the Snowflake cloud). However, I do not have it configured to go through a VPN connection. Is there a way to require that console access is only through VPN?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking about [Network Policies](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/network-policies.html).

Nit: I am not sure "insecure" is the right word to use. All data is transferred over HTTPS and is therefore encrypted. Using SAML you can use your own authentication provider and use MFA. Thus you can easily match the highest standards of security in the industry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can restrict access to your snowflake account using an account-level network policy.

You can define  VPN IP(s) in the allowed IP list in the account level network policy and activate the policy.

After account level activation, everyone is required to connect the VPN before accessing the snowflake account.

Details:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/network-policies.html#managing-account-level-network-policies